# How to make Skype Phone call and recording using Skype API?

Tags: skype, skype-for-business, skypedeveloper

Currently, I have used the below code for Skype call. Its works fine only when the skype is installed.

```
<a href="skype:echo123?call"  target="_blank">Call the Skype Echo / Sound Test Service</a>, If you don't have Skype installed. Download it from <a href='http://www.skype.com'>here</a>
```

I actually need to make a skype call through API? Do any API available for the same?